# Problems importing SVG files

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have installed Gazebo 11 and Inkscape on my MacBook OSX.

I am able to import in model editor the .svg files I create using Inkscape, however the dimensions of the objects do not match with those that I set in Inkscape.

For example, here I tried to create a cylinder extruding a circle of radius 500 mm, while in Gazebo it appears much smaller.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24880/problems-importing-svg-files/) by [Anna](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25769/anna/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe you saved the file with a different resolution? That `Ridimensiona` field looks suspicious.

On Gazebo, you can could increase the `Resolution` field when extruding the SVG.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anna](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25769/anna/) on 2020-04-22**:
Thank you! It worked!